# Group results from a simple xml

Tags: php, xml

I have the following piece of code which gets the following results.

```
$file = 'http://mywebsite.com/test.xml?apikey=*******&API=TEST&limit=30';  
if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file($file))
   exit('Failed to open '.$file);   
$count = 0;
$max = 2;
foreach($xml->computer as $computer){       
   $count++;
   echo '<td class="">'. "<a href='computer.php?cgid=".$computer['group_id'].
      "'>".$computer['name']."</a>";'</td>';
   if($count >= $max){
      $count = 0;
      echo '</tr><tr>';
   }
}
```

Results

```
<computers>
<results totalPages="1" currentPage="1" totalResults="241"/>
   <computer id="14590" group_id="232" model_group="acer" name="Acer 1 GB" />
   <computer id="308382" group_id="232" model_group="acer" name="Acer 2 GB" />
   <computer id="308383" group_id="232" model_group="acer" name="Acer 3 GB" />
   <computer id="302719" group_id="232" model_group="acer" name="Acer 4 GB"/>
   <computer id="308384" group_id="232" model_group="acer" name="Acer 6 GB" />
   <computer id="308385" group_id="232" model_group="acer" name="Acer 8 GB" />
   <computer id="302720" group_id="232" model_group="acer" name="Acer 16 GB" />
   <computer id="308386" group_id="232" model_group="acer" name="Acer 32 GB" />
   <computer id="302715" group_id="232" model_group="acer" name="Acer 48 GB" />
```

What I want to do is group the results, currently i get the name acer repeated in multiple buttons, when i pull the results, what i want to do is show the name Acer just once for all items in that group id?, almost like distinct in a MYSQl Query.

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you add the expected result to your question?

Comment: Thanks, basically i just want to show the name acer oncer for all of the products, at the moment acer is returned as many times as you can see in the results above.  What i want to do is show the name just once for every time the result appears with the same group id, if that makes sense.

Comment: Is that all XML entries respect the same format ? All computer name start by the model_group ?
If no, it will be difficult.

Comment: HI yes that is the output and for example every acer computer has the same group id, the same model group name, etc, with just the name attribute being different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use associative arrays as intermediate variable:

```
groups[groupName][] = item;
```

So item will be added to the end of the list indexed by groupname i.e. 'Acer' in your example.

Code to be clear:

```
$file = 'http://mywebsite.com/test.xml?apikey=*******&API=TEST&limit=30';
if( !$xml = simplexml_load_file( $file )) {
   exit( "Failed to open '$file'" );
}
foreach( $xml->computer as $computer ){
   $index = $computer['model_group'];
   $computerGroups[$index]   = array();
   $computerGroups[$index][] = $computer;
}
foreach( $computerGroups as $groupname => $computers ){       
   foreach( $computer as $computers ){       
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, so in the example above would i change the groupName portion to be model group and then the item section to be name? thanks

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated, i added that to my page and got the following error:  Warning: Illegal offset type in /home/mysite/public_html/computer.php on line 8  which refers to this line  $computerGroups[$computer['model_group']][] = $computer;